# Can someone help how to solve this issue?

Tags: angular, html

I have following html code:
Can some tell How can I fix this table in a proper way so that all headers should align with table data

```
<div class="article-list container">
<table cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="5px" border="1" bgcolor="lightgreen">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <th>User Id</th>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>Body</th>
  <th>Author</th>
  <th>Editor</th>
  <th>Created Date</th>
  <th>Actions</th>
</tr>

<tr *ngFor="let items of article_array_keys" class="structure">
    <p *ngFor="let item of items">
      <td><h5> {{item.id}} </h5></td>
      <td><h5> {{item.title}} </h5></td>
      <td><h5> {{item.body}} </h5></td>
      <td><h5> {{item.author}} </h5></td>
      <td><h5> {{item.editor}} </h5></td>
      <td><h5> {{item.created_at}} </h5></td>
    </p>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

and this is the api data from backend:

```
[{"id":8,"title":"Hello data updated even now","body":"Ducimus et repellendus eveniet ab nihil labore. Autem in nulla vel rerum sit ut omnis. Nulla est sunt minus. Dolores sapiente totam consequuntur omnis officiis voluptas ut.","author":"Velda Lemke","editor":"Sadie Schmidt IV","active":1,"created_at":"2018-09-04 11:27:22","updated_at":"2018-11-06 10:31:11"}]
```

I am using this code in subscribing service in the component:

```
this.serv_article_list.getFullArticleList(this.article_resource['request_type'], this.article_resource)
  .subscribe(
    (article_list_data: any) => { 
      console.log(article_list_data);
      this.article_array_keys = Array.of(article_list_data);//Object.keys(article_list_data)
      // this.article_array_values = Object.values(article_list_data)
    });
```

Can some tell How can I fix this table in a proper way so that all headers should align with table data

note: Whenever I use an extra tag such as `div` or ```span`` inside/outside a  tag it is disturbing the table.
may I be not sure how really a table works with other tags embedded? but they work fine with static HTML code.

SS is attached showing improper formatted table
[image]

I want to achive in this way:

[image]

this is the code access github link:
https://github.com/ROHAN-TANDEL/ng7

Comment: anyone looking for a quick look refer @Rahul Swamynathan 's answer

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let items of article_array_keys" class="structure">
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
      <td><h5> {{item.id}} </h5></td>
      <td><h5> {{item.title}} </h5></td>
      <td><h5> {{item.body}} </h5></td>
      <td><h5> {{item.author}} </h5></td>
      <td><h5> {{item.editor}} </h5></td>
      <td><h5> {{item.created_at}} </h5></td>
    </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Hope this works - happy coding!!

Comment: @peinearydevelopment has given me the hint, and I got my desired result.
BTW your answer reflects exactly what I have done with my code.

Comment: Okay no issues - i didn't see your comments on his answer - if you got the answer then its fine - just proposed the way to achieve the scenario :) Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

There are gaps in the code you provided but judging from the json you pasted, the data is an array while in your template, you are making two `ngFor` as if you had an array of arrays.

Just set the `article_list_data` to a property on your component and iterate over it:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of article_list_data" class="structure">
  <td><h5> {{item.id}} </h5></td>
  <td><h5> {{item.title}} </h5></td>
  <td><h5> {{item.body}} </h5></td>
  <td><h5> {{item.author}} </h5></td>
  <td><h5> {{item.editor}} </h5></td>
  <td><h5> {{item.created_at}} </h5></td>
</tr>
```

**Edit**: To display the content of `article_list_data` as available inside the HTML template, use `<pre>{{ article_list_data | json }}</pre>`.

Judging from your code, `Array.Of(x)` creates an array with a first value `x`. So you end up with an `[[{...}]]` which is the reason why you need a nested `ngFor`.

Remove the `Array.of`:

```
this.serv...getFullArticleList(...)
  .subscribe((article_list_data: any) => { 
     this.article_list_data = article_list_data;
  });
```

Then directly use it.

Comment: I tried that way but does not work out ```there is no output at all.
BTW I printed just after subscribing the ```article_list_data``` for typeof it's showing me as an Object in the console.

Comment: @KrishnanRohan To see the record in your template, use `<pre>{{ article_array_keys | json }}</pre>`. That will show you the content of your variable then you will be able to judge on what to do with it from the `html` template.

Comment: it seems helpful I will try with these technique

Answer (score 0):

It would appear as though your table is being malformed because each table row is only being given one child element

Change your HTML to

```
<tr *ngFor="let items of article_array_keys" class="structure">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
      <td><h5> {{item.id}} </h5></td>
      <td><h5> {{item.title}} </h5></td>
      <td><h5> {{item.body}} </h5></td>
      <td><h5> {{item.author}} </h5></td>
      <td><h5> {{item.editor}} </h5></td>
      <td><h5> {{item.created_at}} </h5></td>
    </ng-container>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked out but ```ng-container``` has to be ```outside``` and ```tr``` should be its ```child```.